# Supress duplicate fields in a crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I got a report which shows data that look something like this:

```
| col1 | col2 |
---------------
|  1   | dfd  |
|  1   | ajd  |
|  1   | aad  |
|  2   | azd  |
|  2   | iod  |
|  3   | asd  |
|  3   | aod  |
|  3   | wsd  |
|  3   | asi  |
```

i want the data look like this:

```
| col1 | col2 |
---------------
|  1   | dfd  |
|      | ajd  |
|      | aad  |
|  2   | azd  |
|      | iod  |
|  3   | asd  |
|      | aod  |
|      | wsd  |
|      | asi  |
```

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

- create a group, based on `col1`
- check the tick "Underlay Following Section" in group-header section of the group